# select gridview to perform edit operation

Tags: selenium

Check the 2 images for html code and operation to be done based on that

I'm using selenium webdriver, I want to click record in the gridview to perform edit/delete Operation, where the viewgrid is in the Iframe having multiple div, tr and td tags. After selecting the record from grid, how to perform the edit/delete Operation?

Here goes the code snippet:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div/iframe/iframe/iframe")));
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/article/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have nested frames. With Selenium, you need to set the context on the parent frame before switching to the nested frame:

```
// set the context on //div/iframe
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);

// set the context on //div/iframe/iframe
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);

// set the context on //div/iframe/iframe/iframe
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);

driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/article/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1]")).Click();
```